# Django model inheritance - accessing the child attributes from the parent

Tags: python, django, database, oop

I am trying to set-up some model inheritance in Django.  I have three classes:

```
class Parent(Model):
    name = TextField()

class Child1(Parent):
    foo = FloatField()

class Child2(Parent):
    bar = BoolField()

class RandomClass(Model):
    myLink = ForignKey(Parent)
```

The problem is in my other models like RandomClass I can get instances of Parent but I cant access the variables specific to the child classes.

I could, of course, just have multiple nullable foreign keys in RandomClass then write a property 'wrapper' which works out which ForeignKey is non-null and returns that...but that's not very nice.

Is there a better way to do this?

Cheers,

Jack

Comment: You might want to check out https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/, a package that aims at making this kind of things easier.

Comment: Hero!  Do you wanna write that up as a quick answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: I know it exists and what its purpose is, but I don't know how to use it, so I'll let someone else provide an example. Or, if you use it, and come up with a satisfying solution, you may also answer your own question. I'll just be glad I could help a bit :)